# Uncaught Not Found Error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one problem :

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

In this file :

```
var AnimeBlock = {
 info: null,
 blocks: null,
 container: null,
 infoContent: null,

 init: function() {
    var i;
    this.info = document.getElementById('anime_info');
    this.infoContent = document.getElementById('anime_info_content');
    this.container = document.getElementById('anime-list');
    this.blocks = this.container.querySelectorAll('[data-type="anime"]');
    for (i = this.blocks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.prepareBlock(this.blocks[i], i);
    }                   
},

prepareBlock: function(block, position) {
    var place = position + (3 - position % 3),
        id = block.getAttribute('data-anime-list'),
        info = block.querySelector('script[type="x-template"][data-anime-type="info"]').innerHTML;
        self = this;
    block.onclick = function() {
        $('.anime_info').css("display","block");
        self.infoContent.innerHTML = info;
        self.container.insertBefore(self.info, self.blocks[place]);
    };
  }
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="anime_news" id="anime-list">
        <!--<div style="display: none;">-->
            <div id="anime_info">
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <div id="anime_info_content" class="anime_info">

                </div>
            </div>
        <!--</div>-->
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can we see the `HTML` as well, or an online demo..?

Comment: YEs!`<div class="anime_news" id="anime-list">
   <!--<div style="display: none;">-->
    <div id="anime_info">
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
     <div id="anime_info_content" class="anime_info">

     </div>
    </div>
   <!--</div>-->`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and update it there... code blocks are really not readable in comments...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `self.blocks[place]` does not belong to `self.container`. But since `self.info` does, I think you wanted:

```
self.container.insertBefore(self.blocks[place], self.info);
```

*(First argument is the new node to insert)*